# Python makes wrong hashes of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ran into a hashing problem:
I’m trying to hash using HMAC-SHA1

On Python 3.9 I use this code:

```
import hmac
import json
from hashlib import sha1

secret = "1b87e199bb4791db3f0920784e14c91df6c83df9"
dic = {'name':'Andrew',
       'color':'white'}
sign = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'),json.dumps(dic).encode('utf-8'),sha1).hexdigest()
```

> 83de79802d654cd6b94b6561dad1b882c918f3f5

But using almost the same code on PHP I get more correct result (the result I need)

```
$dic =json_encode([
    "name" => "Andrew",
    "color" => "white",
]);
$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $dic, $secret);
```

> d6b6305ebc39b44d10160c80a95f65faff0167b9

My secret: `1b87e199bb4791db3f0920784e14c91df6c83df9`

What’s whong with my dict hashing on Python, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could share the example with a `secret` that you can tell us ? So we can reproduce ?

Comment: What makes the PHP result "more correct"?

Comment: There are multiple valid encodings of the same JSON document, so the fact that they give different results doesn't mean that one of them is wrong.

Comment: I'm very interested to know why you deem the PHP generated hash to be *"more correct result"*

Comment: In both case it's a hash of the json representation, not of a dictionary. And there are many ways to represent a dictionary as json (different order and whitespace). You'll need some canonical representation to make the hash stable.

Comment: Added secret to the post

Comment: I meant "more correct" because this hash from PHP is successfully working with API, but hash from Python doesn't work with API

Comment: Can you please provide the JSON literals in addition to / instead of the initial mappings? Not everyone who can help you with the Python part of the problem wants to dig through the PHP part...

Comment: At the very least, have you compared the results of `json_encode` in PHP and `json.dumps` in Python?

Comment: json literals from PHP:

{"name":"Andrew","color":"white"}

Comment: @Felix [edit] that into your question, preferably formatted as code with code fences. Whitespace can make a difference to the hash, so make sure both json literals are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `json_encode` outputs without whitespace:

```
{"name":"Andrew","color":"white"}
```

Whereas Python's `json.dumps()`:

```
{"name": "Andrew", "color": "white"}
```

You can use `json.dumps(dic, separators=(',', ':'))` to get the same output as PHP.